Boundary conditions of series expansion perturbation
Background
In the book Mathematics Applied to Deterministic Problems in the Natural Sciences by Lin and Segel at chapter 7.2, they show the Projectile Problem Solved by Perturbation Theory.
Basically, they use those conditions:
$$\ddot{x}=-(1+\epsilon x)^{-2}, x(0)=0, \dot{x}=1$$
a series expansion
$$x(t,\epsilon)=x_0(t)+\epsilon x_1+\epsilon^2x_2(t)+...$$
and equate the various powers of $\epsilon$ to zero to find a set of differential equations for solving each $x_i$.
However, the book states that the initial conditions for every $x_i$ is slightly different. Specifically,
$$\dot{x}_0(0)=1$$
while
$$\dot{x}_1(0)=\dot{x}_2(0)=0$$
Questions

Why are the boundary conditions different?
Why should all various powers of $\epsilon$ be equal to zero? Could it change if the initial equation was different?

